# Emacs DocumentView: how to see PDF contents page?

Tags: pdf, emacs

Basically what the title says - if I open a PDF using Emacs' DocumentView, how can I bring up the PDF's contents page? Also, how would I 'jump' to a particular page in the PDF (from the contents page if possible).